# Deploy DRF project using Docker Compose with JSON environment variable setting

Tags: json, django, docker, django-rest-framework, docker-compose

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPWH5.png)

```
{
  "SECRET_KEY": "",
  "EMAIL_HOST_USER": "",
  "EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD": "",
  "SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID": "",
  "SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_SECRET": "",
  "SOCIAL_AUTH_KAKAO_CLIENT_ID": "",
  "KAKAO_REST_API_KEY": "",
  "SOCIAL_AUTH_NAVER_CLIENT_ID": "",
  "SOCIAL_AUTH_NAVER_SECRET": "",
  "SOCIAL_AUTH_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID": "",
  "SOCIAL_AUTH_GITHUB_SECRET": "",
  "STATE": "random_string",
  "DATABASES": {
    "default": {
      "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
      "HOST": "",
      "PORT": 5432,
      "NAME": "",
      "USER": "",
      "PASSWORD": ""
    }
  }
}
```

secrets.json

```
version: '3.8'

volumes:
  postgres: {}
  django_media: {}
  django_static: {}

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:15.3
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      ./backend/django/secrets.json
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD
      - POSTGRES_NAME
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build: ./backend/
    entrypoint: sh -c "python manage.py collectstatic --no-input && python manage.py migrate && gunicorn Realby_project.wsgi --workers=5 -b 0.0.0.0:800
00"
    volumes:
      - ./backend/django/:/app/
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - django_media:/app/media/
      - django_static:/app/static/
      - ./backend/django/secrets.json:/app/secrets.json
    environment:
      - DEBUG=1
      - POSTGRES_NAME=${POSTGRES_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_HOST=${POSTGRES_HOST}
      - POSTGRES_PORT=${POSTGRES_PORT}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    restart: always

  nginx:
    container_name : nginx
    image: nginx:1.23.2
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - django_media:/media/
      - django_static:/static/
    depends_on:
      - backend
    restart: always
```

docker-compose.yml

I want deploy with docker-compose using .json for enviroment
but Docker Compose can not read this .json file

How can i fix this files

When i asked chatGPT he said
make entrypoint.sh and worte this script

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS="=" read -r key value; do
  if [[ "$key" != "" && "$value" != "" ]]; then
    export "$key"="$value"
  fi
done < /app/secrets.json


python manage.py collectstatic --no-input
python manage.py migrate
gunicorn Realby_project.wsgi --workers=5 -b 0.0.0.0:8000
```

and set entrypoint in docker-compose.yml like `entrypoint: ./backend/entrypoint.sh`

but same...

please help

I can't search for like this case.
NO ONE NOBODY USE JSON ENVIROMENT
i'm so sad

I'm not good at English, so please understand

Comment: If you want an easy solution, use an .env file, as this is what docker natively supports.

Comment: You've included a PNG file and a JSON file at the start of the question; how do you expect your application to use these files?  How do you reference the files in your application-level configuration (not necessarily Docker-specific, how does the application know to read the JSON file)?  Are you getting an error message or any other output that you could include in the question in plain text?